# The toughest part to me or for me?

Tags: grammar

Which of these sentences is correct?

A) This is the toughest part to me.
B) This is the hardest part for me.
C) This is the toughest part for me.
D) This is the hardest part to me.

Comment: They all could be right. What is the context? What do you want this to mean?

Comment: @Laurel Whilst I see the similarity, the accepted answer in the linked answer would seem to imply that using 'to me' in any of these instances would be preferred, which certainly seems to me to be incorrect.

Comment: @Laurel perhaps even, the linked answer gives a wrong answer, whilst it's accepted. To me and for me in that answer imply very different things, for me being literally for me, that is the 'feeling' and the 'act,' whilst 'to me' is just the feeling (for me implies that the speaker could do it, to me implies that the speaker and ~anyone could do it)

Answer (score 0):

A & D both have 'issues' (wanting something like the intransitive verb 'seems' a la
"This seems the toughest part to me."

In any case, both the *to* examples have different meanings to the *for* examples, A & D can imply that the object itself is hard, rather than the action(which is what I think you're trying to communicate)

B & C (the 'for' sentences) both carry the meaning that the verb is difficult (that you will find this particular act more difficult than the rest of a series acts.)

Examples:

A) (Points at section of 'recycled' lumber) This seems the toughest part to me

B) (Just about to shift gear for the first time in front of Examiner) This is the hardest part for me.

C) (Just about to shift gear for the first time in front of Examiner)This is the toughest part for me.

D) (See A)This is the hardest part to me.

I'm not sure D really works in that sense, as the adverb/adjective hard looks odd to me anyway in either sense :S

Comment: aaand, there's something that makes this answer wrong?

Comment: I’m not crazy about your “A and D have issues” statement.

Comment: @Jim Well, the answer is bad really anyway, looking at it again. It's just an opinion piece, though I think the opinion is correct, heh. Having said that, the accepted answer in the linked question is no better.